# Case expression - comparing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the query below, if the deadline column (eh.Deadline) < today (getdate) then returns 1, else 0.

```
(case when he.Deadline < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111) then 1 else 0 end) Deadline
```

Everything works fine, but I need to change it so that only the month and the year (not the day), are compared.

Example, if Deadline=10/01/2022 and today=11/01/2022

- My query returns 1 (10/01/2022 < 11/01/2022)
- I would like to compare only the month and the year -  I would like it to return 0 as MM/YYYY it's the same (01/2022 = 01/2022)

**EDIT:**

The column he.Deadline has the following format: DD/MM/YYYY HH/MM and this could not be compared to GETDATE and to solve that I had to use CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111) instead of GETDATE

The above query is used for a dashboard I created, and I wouldn't want to change anything in the database.

All I want is to compare MM/YYYY instead of DD/MM/YYYY

Any ideas please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: And why would you convert a date into a string before comparing it? Compare dates as dates and strings as strings... don't mix them.

Comment: the column he.Deadline has the following format: DD/MM/YYYY HH/MM and this could not be compared to GETDATE.
and to solve that I had to use CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111) instead of Getdate

Comment: Yeah, but you are now doing a string compare which isn't what you want either. You should be storing your dates as the correct datatype otherwise you are doing to have issues for the life of the project.

Comment: Please [edit] into your question your exact sample data as that makes a big difference.

Comment: Is *Deadline* a *date* datatype or a *string*? Please clarify.

Comment: `the column he.Deadline has the following format: DD/MM/YYYY HH/MM` < WHY? Please fix it. It should probably be `datetime2` (once you ensure that none of the data is actually `MM/DD/YYYY` and that other garbage hasn't found its way in there too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do `(case when EOMONTH(he.Deadline) < EOMONTH(GETDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) Deadline`

set the date to last day of the month for both values before comparing them so only the month/year will matter in the end

edit: as long as `Deadline` is a `date`... if it isn't then you have to convert it to `date` before calling `EOMONTH` on it

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to ensure you are comparing a datetime/date with a datetime/date not a string with a datetime, nor a string with a string, as the comparisons are different all different, and your desired result is comparing a date.

Then you should be storing your data in the correct datatype, which for a datetime is a `datetime2`. Storing your `Deadline` as a string is going to cause you pain and trouble for the life of the project and will perform badly.

However with the situation as it is, you need to first convert your `Deadline` column correctly into a date value, and then secondly one way to solve your actual problem is to compare to the first of the current month as follows:

```
select
    -- Convert to a date datatype in order to be able to correctly compare to another date
    convert(date,substring(he.Deadline,1,10),103) -- Ensure dd/mm/yyyy as opposed to mm/dd/yyyy
    <
    -- Calculate the first of the month and check whether the Deadline is before then
    convert(date,dateadd(day, -1*(datepart(day,getdate())-1), getdate())) then 1 else 0 end Deadline
from (
  values ('10/01/2022 12/30')
) he (Deadline)
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand good call - updated - thanks.

Comment: (Also not to nit-pick but I find "first day of this month" much easier to calculate [using `DATEFROMPARTS`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a416a24a1bea416de3f74db846593c7).)